# Definition: How can you tell if a coordinate system is "generalized coordinates" or not?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, definition

I'm trying to remember this stuff and using only [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_coordinates) and not textbooks which is probably part of the confusion.

But what is the *precise* definition of a "generalized" as opposed to a "not generalized" coordinate system for a given problem?

And by that I mean, if you assume the coordinate system is valid and each point uniquely determines the configuration of the system, what other information do you need to determine the answer to the question?

Answer (score 1):

A set of generalised co-ordinates is any set of parameters that maps to the configuration space of a system in a one-to-one or many-to-one relationship. The term “generalised” is simply there to remind us that these parameters are not necessarily spatial co-ordinates - although some or all of them may be.

A set of non-generalised co-ordinates (if there even is such a term) would be a set of parameters that did not uniquely define a system configuration. For example, if an object was free to move in three dimensions, but we only had x and y co-ordinates for its position, these would not be a set of generalised co-ordinates.

See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_coordinates) for more details.

Comment: Ah ok, so "generalized" is really rather a deep conversation about what we think is "easy" and "default" coordinates I guess. If the coordinate system uniquely defines the configuration it is "generalized" unless it is the "standard coordinate system" but maybe we even would call that generalized or something like that?

For a 2d system embedded in 3d, if we used 3d coords, that could still be "generalized"? Or are constraints not allowed. Is there some strict notion of "free space" baked into these definitions?

Comment: @mathtick You may be overthinking this. Standard spatial co-ordinates can be (and often are) part of a set of generalised co-ordinates. A set of generalised co-ordinates can also contain redundant information. For example, we could use x,y,z co-ordinates to define the position of an object that is constrained to move on the surface of a sphere, even though we know the position can be uniquely defined with just two parameters.

Comment: It sounds like I have a slightly false memory about the definitions but there is some notion of "conjugate momenta" that seems to constrain choices somewhat. I will post a screen shot of the one of the bits on Wikipedia. Sorry if this is annoying, often discussions about definitions are pretty annoying.

Comment: @gandalf61 Can you please elaborate by what you mean by "set of parameters that maps to the configuration space of a system in a one-to-one or many-to-one relationship"? Aren't the parameters themselves define the configuration space?

Comment: @AntoniosSarikas The parameters are distinct from the configuration space because the configuration space may be parametrised in many, many different ways.

Comment: @gandalf61 Then I must misunderstand something because Wikipedia states: "In classical mechanics, the parameters that define the configuration of a system are called generalized coordinates, and the space defined by these coordinates is called the configuration space of the physical system".